# How do we disable - not hide - scrollbars in a browser using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to disable browser's scrolling when an event happens, but not remove the scrollbar ?

I would like something very similar to setting CSS's `overflow:hidden` to the whole document. My reason is that doing so changes the browser's width, hence I will have to re-align the body.

Comment: `"hence I will have to re-align the body"` - ???

Comment: I do not want to change the current view of the page. 

I see the width of display portion changes. I prefer to be in the same condition, something like the image taken of the page, with scrolling disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practise fix to the problem I *think* you're describing is this simple CSS:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll
}
```

That forces the vertical scrollbar to always be visible, so that the browser's width will not change "when an event happens", and you won't "have to re-align the body".

Comment: I cannot see any change. Everything remains the same.

Comment: Is there a link I can look at? Or, can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo of your page?

Comment: I think the part you are missing is disabling the scroll mechanism i.e. he no longer wants the page to be scrollable when an event happens, but he still wants the scrollbars to show all the time so as not to mess up the layout/alignment.

Comment: Yes thank you tw16. I am sorry I could not explain it good enough. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: @maan81: That's very bad from a user experience perspective. Also: you can't disable the scrollbars if they're visible. The best you can do is: if the user scrolls, set the scroll position back to what it was, but then it's like the user moving the scrollbar and your code moving it back are "having a fight". So, you can either detect the width of the scrollbar, hide it, and add the same amount of `padding-right` to `body`, or my personal favourite: **just forget about this and leave the scrollbar alone**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the entire web page to align:center? No manual re-aligning, and works with any screen resolution or browser :-)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that you should use 'align:center' in conjunction with 'overflow:hidden' .