# Deactivate browser scrollbar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lightbox displaying various content:

```
$('.mehr').click(function() {
$('#lightbox').css({'visibility' : 'visible'}).animate({'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
});

$('.close').click(function() {
$('#lightbox').stop().animate({'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'opacity': '0'}, 500, function(){$(this).css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});});
});
```

I need to prevent the user from scrolling when #lightbox is visible. Is there a way to deactivate the browser's scrollbars when #lightbox becomes visible and then reactivate them when #lightbox is closed?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7146130/1029433

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this code hide the scroll using css

```
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

In JQuery

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

For Internet Explorer 6, just overflow the html

```
$("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

Comment: In this case it will be hidden and deactivated

Answer (score 0):

While setting the overflow attribute to hidden just hides the scrollbar you can "lock" the current scrollposition with jQuery like this:

```
$('.mehr').click(function() {
$('#lightbox').css({'visibility' : 'visible'}).animate({'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
lockPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
        $(this).scrollTop(lockPosition);
    });
});

$('.close').click(function() {
$('#lightbox').stop().animate({'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'opacity': '0'}, 500, function(){$(this).css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});});
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
    });
});
```

FIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kjzr/